# angular: how to set cookies in intercepted response header?

Tags: angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

I am new to web-deveopment and to angularJS. I know how to intercept a response using angular interceptors. I now want to add cookies to to this response, which can be later accessed using `$cookieStore.get('DEMO_COOKIE')`..How do I do it? Basically I want to know the following patch of code:

```
angular.module('APP').factory('myInterceptor', function() {
        return {
            response: function(response) {
                // code here for modifying incoming response by adding cookies to it 
                /*
                 Or Is this the right way to do it?
                 response.headers()['Set-Cookie']= 'DEMO_COOKIE=demo_session; expires=Sat, 18 Oct 2014 23:38:25 GMT; username=public; role=public';
                */
              return response
            }
        }
  })


   angular.module('APP').config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
    }]);
```

With the current code I get undefined value for `$cookieStore.get('DEMO_COOKIE')`. However if the above code is correct than that may be due to some other error in my code.Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by injecting `$cookieStore` to your interceptor. Then you can use `$cookieStore.put()` method to add a cookie:

```
angular.module('APP').factory('myInterceptor', ['$cookieStore', function ($cookieStore) {
    return {
        response: function (response) {
            $cookieStore.put('DEMO_COOKIE', 'I am a cookie!!!');
            return response;
        }
    };
}]);


angular.module('APP').config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
}]);
```

Comment: The above solution works but I think it could be done by using any globally available array (and not only $cookieStore).So in a way its not a modification of original response header rather , in this solution, $cookieStore is just working as a global service to communicate data. Actually I am working in a backendless environment and I am trying to immitate the exact response from server which contains cookies in its headers.I have set up a virtual backend using grunt which serves the response but I cant serve cookies through it.(Please guide me if I am wrong). Is there a way to achieve it?